# Mailchimp extension not pushing new Civi group members to the Mailchimp list

Tags: smartgroups, mailchimp

I've been setting up the excellent Mailchimp extension from Vedaconsulting.

It all seems to be working correctly (thanks to [this page](https://vedaconsulting.co.uk/civicrm-mailchimp)), except for when posting on the fly from Civicrm to Mailchimp:

I've setup a smart group to correspond to a list in Mailchimp. 
If I unsubscribe someone from Mailchimp then Mailchimp's webhook fires and the person is correctly removed from the smart group.

But if I add someone to the smartgroup they aren't being pushed to Mailchimp. There is immediate activity in the Civicrm log, but the name of the person isn't included. (Arrays contain info about the list and groups etc, but not the person.) And no change in Mailchimp.

Nevertheless, syncing Civi from/to Mailchimp seems to be working fine.

What could I do to troubleshoot this?

We're on Drupal 7.50, Civicrm 4.6.17, Mailchimp 1.8.7. Our server is locked down pretty tight... but if syncing is working then I would have thought the database post should be working too?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? We are having the same issue on V2 of the module.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions page you linked to is for an old version, which you must be on if you have 1.8.7.

I wrote version 2 of this extension and it's fairly a complete rewrite, so while I can't promise it solves your problem, I can say that no further development is going to happen on 1.8.x.

You need to update to v.2 before the end of 2016 as Mailchimp are apparently pulling their old API, so your integration will probably stop working. Veda have most of my code "merged in master" (means they've accepted it) but have not published a release.

I have published a release, though, at https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/releases

It's flagged with a red beta tag at the mo because it brings in an experimental webhook thing for WordPress users, but I'm guessing you're on Drupal, so you can ignore the beta bit - I have been running this version in production for a few months now. But you should see the [README](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/blob/master/README.md) as the new Mailchimp API changes a lot. I'd definitely recommend a backup of your Mailchimp lists ("exports" from Mailchimp) and your CiviCRM set up before you go upgrading. Of course you would anyway :-)

Comment: Can you assist with this; https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/283 ?